# Swift 3 new update. Why is my navigation title double the size it was before the update?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I have an app with an image set as navigation bar title. I had it the perfect size but since I updated my iPhone and mac/xcode the image is the actual size of the image and not what its set to. How do I fix this? Thanks.

```
var titleView : UIImageView

titleView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))

titleView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

titleView.image = UIImage(named: "logo.png")

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use like this :

```
var titleView : UIImageView

titleView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
let widthConstraint = titleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32)
let heightConstraint = titleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32)
heightConstraint.isActive = true
widthConstraint.isActive = true
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Just had to adjust the sizes.

Answer (score 0):

To add a slightly different way of doing it:

When using autolayout, it's not worth setting the frame of your views, because they are going to be overridden in the layout pass, so I'd do it this way, comments added to explain what I'm doing:

```
// Unless you are going to recreate the view, just use a let not a var.
// A UIImageView is a reference type, so you can still change the image to be displayed.
// Also, there is no point declaring a variable and then setting it on the next line, just do it all at once.
// Using the non-parameterised initialiser uses a zero frame for the rect.
let titleView = UIImageView()

// Since the view is being created in code and autolayout is going to be applied, you need to add this line to prevent layout conflicts.
titleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// Configure the aspect ratio of the displayed image.
titleView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

// You don't need to keep a reference to the constraint unless you want to activate and deactivate it.
titleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true

// Now, since you want the image to be a square, you can create an layout anchor that specifies this requirement, rather than just duplicating the width value.
titleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
```